# MySQL Procedure Returns 0 Rows

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, latitude-longitude

I have a MySQL script (using Workbench) that identifies the distance of locations from a set coordinate pair. Those locations that are within a certain radius are brought back and a number of calculations are made on those rows.

The problem is that when I run the query using variables but not in a procedure the script works as I would expect. When I turn it into a stored procedure, it doesn't matter what lat/long variables I put in no rows are returned. However, no error is thrown.

I have selected out the lat/long variable that I enter in the proc and they look as expected i.e. they have the correct number of decimal places.

Would be very grateful if someone could take a look and advise. Thank you!

Both scripts are shown below.

```
/*Code run outside of procedure:*/

Set @Radius = 200,
@Latitude = 40.76,
@Longitude = -73.97;

Select
   *
From

          (
        Select
          b.ID,
          b.ContractID,
          b.InsuredName,
          b.UserDefined1,
          b.Line,
          b.Limit,
          b.Excess,
          b.Deductible,
          sum(b.TIV) TIV,
            case 
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) >= b.Limit then (b.Limit * b.Line)
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) < b.Limit and sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) > 0 then (sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible)) * b.Line
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) <= 0 then 0 end Exposure$
        From

                (
                Select
                  a.ID,
                  a.ContractID,
                  a.InsuredName,
                  a.UserDefined1,
                  a.Line,
                  a.Limit,
                  a.Excess,
                  a.Deductible,
                  TIV
                From

                      (
                        Select
                            a.ID,
                            a.ContractID,
                            a.InsuredName,
                            a.UserDefined1,
                            a.Line,
                            a.Limit,
                            a.Excess,
                            a.Deductible,
                            TIV,
                            case when cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(@Latitude))* cos(radians(@Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(@Latitude)) > 1 
                                then sign(cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(@Latitude))* cos(radians(@Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(@Latitude))) 
                                else (6378100 * acos(cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(@Latitude))* cos(radians(@Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(@Latitude)))) 
                                end Distance
                        From
                            Location l
                            inner join Account a on a.ID = l.ID
                            )a
                        Where
                          a.Distance <= @Radius

                )b

        Group by
          b.ID,
          b.ContractID,
          b.InsuredName,
          b.UserDefined1,
          b.Line,
          b.Limit,
          b.Excess,
          b.Deductible
        )c
Where
  c.Exposure$ > 0

/*Stored procedure (returning 0 rows):*/

Delimiter //

Create Procedure sp_RingAccounts (in Radius int, in Latitude decimal(9,6), in Longitude decimal(9,6))

Begin

Select Latitude;
Select Longitude;
Select Radius;

Select
   *
From

          (
        Select
          b.ID,
          b.ContractID,
          b.InsuredName,
          b.UserDefined1,
          b.Line,
          b.Limit,
          b.Excess,
          b.Deductible,
          sum(b.TIV) TIV,
            case 
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) >= b.Limit then (b.Limit * b.Line)
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) < b.Limit and sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) > 0 then (sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible)) * b.Line
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) <= 0 then 0 end Exposure$
        From

                (
                Select
                  a.ID,
                  a.ContractID,
                  a.InsuredName,
                  a.UserDefined1,
                  a.Line,
                  a.Limit,
                  a.Excess,
                  a.Deductible,
                  TIV
                From

                      (
                        Select
                            a.ID,
                            a.ContractID,
                            a.InsuredName,
                            a.UserDefined1,
                            a.Line,
                            a.Limit,
                            a.Excess,
                            a.Deductible,
                            TIV,
                            case when cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(@Latitude))* cos(radians(@Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(@Latitude)) > 1 
                                then sign(cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(@Latitude))* cos(radians(@Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(@Latitude))) 
                                else (6378100 * acos(cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(@Latitude))* cos(radians(@Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(@Latitude)))) 
                                end Distance
                        From
                            Location l
                            inner join Account a on a.ID = l.ID
                            )a
                        Where
                          a.Distance <= @Radius

                )b

        Group by
          b.ID,
          b.ContractID,
          b.InsuredName,
          b.UserDefined1,
          b.Line,
          b.Limit,
          b.Excess,
          b.Deductible
        )c
Where
  c.Exposure$ > 0 ;

End ;

 //
 Delimiter ;
```

Comment: Any ideas? Anyone? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have found what the issue was, I was using @ in front of my variable in the procedure body, which I didn't need to.

So I was putting @Latitude when I just needed to use 'Latitude'. Probably should had spotted this a lot earlier. I think the fact that it wasn't giving me an error from doing this threw me off and also being biased from what I know using SSMS making me put the @ in front of the variables.

Working script now looks like:

```
Delimiter //

Create Procedure sp_RingAccounts (in Radius int, in Latitude decimal(9,6), in Longitude decimal(9,6))

Begin

Select
   *
From

          (
        Select
          b.ID,
          b.ContractID,
          b.InsuredName,
          b.UserDefined1,
          b.Line,
          b.Limit,
          b.Excess,
          b.Deductible,
          sum(b.TIV) TIV,
            case 
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) >= b.Limit then (b.Limit * b.Line)
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) < b.Limit and sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) > 0 then (sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible)) * b.Line
            when sum(b.TIV) - (b.Excess + b.Deductible) <= 0 then 0 end Exposure$
        From

                (
                Select
                  a.ID,
                  a.ContractID,
                  a.InsuredName,
                  a.UserDefined1,
                  a.Line,
                  a.Limit,
                  a.Excess,
                  a.Deductible,
                  TIV
                From

                      (
                        Select
                            a.ID,
                            a.ContractID,
                            a.InsuredName,
                            a.UserDefined1,
                            a.Line,
                            a.Limit,
                            a.Excess,
                            a.Deductible,
                            TIV,
                            case when cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(Latitude))* cos(radians(Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(Latitude)) > 1 
                                then sign(cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(Latitude))* cos(radians(Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(Latitude))) 
                                else (6378100 * acos(cos(radians(l.Latitude))*cos(radians(Latitude))* cos(radians(Longitude)- radians(l.Longitude))+ sin(radians(l.Latitude))* sin(radians(Latitude)))) 
                                end Distance
                        From
                            Location l
                            inner join Account a on a.ID = l.ID
                            )a
                        Where
                          a.Distance <= Radius

                )b

        Group by
          b.ID,
          b.ContractID,
          b.InsuredName,
          b.UserDefined1,
          b.Line,
          b.Limit,
          b.Excess,
          b.Deductible
        )c
Where
  c.Exposure$ > 0 ;

End ;

 //
 Delimiter ;
```

Thanks,
Jourden